# Can I convert all blobs in a file to text?

Tags: mysql, search, blob

I have a `db.sql` dump of a MYSQL database that I need to look through for certain data, and wonder what the simplest way to get this all as text is?

I don't want to change the actual database, just get a human readable (and machine searchable) version of it. I also have access to the database so a tool that can search through *all the tables* for text in a blob would be as useful.

Comment: You do realize that a .sql file is a list of SQL queries, right?  There's a high probability that simple searching the .sql file for the text strings you're looking for will "just work".  Otherwise, dump, export to something friendly.

Comment: yes I realize that. The text is stored as blobs which I can't just search through.

Comment: In what format is the `BLOB` data?  Hex strings `0x...`?

Comment: They start with 0x then a bunch of hex, so I'd say yes.